# An error of a template tag

Tags: python, django

I have one django project and one application in it. I want to get a **simple** custom template tag to work. So I created a python file:

```
#my_site/settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #.....    
    'my_app'
)


#my_site/my_app/templatetags/my_app/say_hello_tag.py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def say_hello(model_instance):
    return model_instance.say_hello()

#my_site/my_app/templates/my_app/my_model_list.html
{% load say_hello_tag %}
....................................
<td>{% say_hello object %}</td>
```

And the error is:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /my_app_base_dir/
'say_hello_tag' is not a valid tag library: Template library say_hello_tag not found, tried django.templatetags.say_hello_tag, django.contrib.admin.templatetags.say_hello_tag, django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.say_hello_tag
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: You might have to restart the server to get the tag loaded

Comment: @dazedconfused, restarted.

Comment: Do you have `__ init __.py` in your templatetags directory?

Comment: @dazedconfused, no, what should be in it?

Comment: @dazedconfused, it's a folder, isn't a separate application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the Django [Custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout)

> The app should contain a templatetags directory, at the same level as
>   models.py, views.py, etc. If this doesn’t already exist, create it -
>   **don’t forget the `__init__.py` file to ensure the directory is treated
>   as a Python package**. After adding this module, you will need to
>   restart your server before you can use the tags or filters in
>   templates.
>
> For example, if your custom tags/filters are in a file called
>   poll_extras.py, your app layout might look like this:

```
polls/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        poll_extras.py
    views.py
```

Your directory structure should be something like:

```
my_site/
    my_app/
        __init__.py
        templatetags/
            __init__.py
            say_hello_tag.py
        models.py
        view.py
        ...
```

I think you'll have to follow the structure layout stated the Django documentation in order to get this right.

Comment: but my folder structure is different. what's "polls" here: the website or an application?

Comment: my template tag is in "#my_site/my_app/templatetags/my_app/say_hello_tag.py". Where should  I put **__init__.py**?

Comment: `polls` here is an application

Comment: Why would you have a `my_app` directory inside `templatetags`?

Comment: 1) So should I put init.py in templatetags/__init.py or templatetags/my_app/__init.py ? 2) What if I have more that one custom tags in say_hello_tag.py?

Comment: **Why would you have a my_app directory inside template tags?** - due to convention, but that's not important. I have the same structure for "templates" and it's working fine.

Comment: well, it's working but isn't there a way to make it work with my actual project structure? Tell Django where to find my templatetags?  So I can have it in  **"#my_site/my_app/templatetags/my_app/say_hello_tag.py".**

Comment: Not sure about this, but I'm afraid not; based on the document, the entire `templatetags` directory is treated as a Python package